# Preference not being removed across all contexts

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have a preference Util class that looks like this:

```
public class PreferenceUtils {
    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(final Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public static String getToken(final Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context);
        return sp.getString("TOKEN", null);
    }

    public static void setToken(final Context context, final String token) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context);
        sp.edit().putString("TOKEN", token).apply();
    }
}
```

The problem is, if I try to remove the "TOKEN" preference from one context (`MainActivity`, for example):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceUtils.getSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.remove("TOKEN");
editor.apply();
```

It still exists if I call it from a different context (`UserActivity`, for example).

How can I remove the TOKEN preference across the entire app? Should I be handling my preferences differently in my Util class?

Comment: your code looks fine. Can you try commit instead of apply?

Comment: Same results with commit. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
editor.putString("TOKEN", "");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your getSharedPreferences method like this:

```
public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(final Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
}
```

At the moment you are getting shared preferences with different contexts, so it may cause problems.